# CKEDITOR mathjax formula is not loading properly in jquery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Iam trying to display mathjax formula in ckeditor. If page reloads , the formula is loading propoerly in ckeditor , if it's jquery function call ckeditor formula is not loading properly. I want to load the mathjax formula properly through jquery function. Iam using ckeditor version "4.4.6 DEV"

formula is displaying in ckeditor while triggers jquery to load data into ckeditor:

(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a})

code is:

```
// To load data in ckeditor
$('#cke_editor1 iframe').contents().find('body').html(element.body);

//ckeditor code
$('#editor1').ckeditor(
    function(){
      editorReady = true;
      // global!
      // used to be an assumption in jquery.init.editor.js
      // callback means we can always tell for sure, this helps with jasmine tests
    },
    {
      skin: 'cgp',
      forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
      resize_enabled: true,
      height: 450,
      extraPlugins: 'embed,attachment,multimedia,cg_inputctrl,footnotes',
        //,mathjax
        // mathJaxLib: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        // mathJaxClass: 'equation',
      toolbarCanCollapse: false,
      magicline_everywhere: true,
      magicline_tabuList: ['data-tabu'],
      toolbar:[
            [ 'Italic',
                'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote','Footnotes','Superscript', 'Subscript', 'Table', 'SpecialChar', 'Mathjax',
                'Link', 'Unlink',
                'simpleImage', 'flvPlayer', 'flvPlayerAudio', 'Attachment', 'oembed',
                'Copy', 'Paste', 'Find',
                'Undo', 'Redo',
                'Maximize']],
      keystrokes:
        [
          [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 121 /*F10*/, 'toolbarFocus' ],
          [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 122 /*F11*/, 'elementsPathFocus' ],

          [ CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 121 /*F10*/, 'contextMenu' ],

          [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 90 /*Z*/, 'undo' ],
          [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 89 /*Y*/, 'redo' ],
          [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 90 /*Z*/, 'redo' ],

          [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 76 /*L*/, 'link' ],

          [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 73 /*I*/, 'italic' ],

          [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 109 /*-*/, 'toolbarCollapse' ],
          [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 66 /*B*/, 'doNothing' ],
          [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 85 /*U*/, 'doNothing' ]
        ],
      contentsCss: [ CKEDITOR.basePath + 'contents.css',
                     "<%= application_asset_path('cg_gui/annotations.css') %>"],

      filebrowserBrowseUrl: urlFor("/cg_ck_multimedia/attachments"),
      filebrowserSimpleImageBrowseLinkUrl: urlFor("/cg_ck_multimedia/images"),
      // video custom placeholder images also browsed here
      filebrowserSimpleImageBrowseUrl: urlFor("/cg_ck_multimedia/images"),
      filebrowserFlvPlayerBrowseUrl: urlFor("/cg_ck_multimedia/videos"),
      filebrowserFlvPlayerAudioBrowseUrl: urlFor("/cg_ck_multimedia/audios"),
      // ckeditor window widths should be >= 640wx420h or ckeditor will resize them
      filebrowserSimpleImageWindowWidth: 920,
      filebrowserSimpleImageWindowHeight: 535,
      filebrowserFlvPlayerWindowWidth: 920,
      filebrowserFlvPlayerWindowHeight: 535,
      filebrowserFlvPlayerAudioWindowWidth: 920,
      filebrowserFlvPlayerAudioWindowHeight: 535,
      filebrowserWindowWidth: 920,
      filebrowserWindowHeight: 535,
      filebrowserSimpleImageUploadUrl: urlFor("/cg_ck_multimedia/images"),
      filebrowserFlvPlayerUploadUrl: urlFor("/cg_ck_multimedia/videos"),
      filebrowserFlvPlayerAudioUploadUrl: urlFor("/cg_ck_multimedia/audios"),
      filebrowserUploadUrl: urlFor("/cg_ck_multimedia/attachments")

    });
    })();
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to dynamically modify editor HTML e.g. by ajax call and add content containing mathjax formula.

The problem with your code is that you are trying to manually modify editor HTML using jQuery, so it won't be able to parse mathjax formula. You should always modify editor content using its functions. E.g. you could use [`editor.setData`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setData) function to set content with mathjax formula:

```
editor.setData( '<p>A<span class="math-tex">\\(1 + 1 = 2\\)</span>B</p>' );
```

Also, don't forget that you have to wrap mathjax formula with `span` element and correct class name which could be changed using [`CKEDITOR.config.mathjaxClass`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-mathJaxClass) configuration property. The default one is `math-tex`.